# QString empties while passing to function

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qstring

I have a project written with QT.
So far I tested it in Windows without problems.
Today I tried to port it to Linux

I downloaded the Qt source tree from qt.gitorius.org. For now it have version 5.2.2.
It compiled and installed without problem.
Program also compiled without problem.
But there was a problem while running.
While debugging I found strange behavior.
Shortly in code:

```cpp
Config::Config()
{
    p_path = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
    if(!p_path.endsWith(QDir::separator())) p_path += QDir::separator();
    QString path = p_path + "Settings/config.xml";
    settings = new Settings(path,this); // here path is /opt/myprog/Settings/config.xml
}
Settings::Settings(const QString file, QObject * parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    p_file = file; // file is empty here!!!!   
    p_initialized = false;
    p_autosave = true;
    p_changed = false;

}
```

When I pass QString value to function it loses its value.

I checked the same code in Windows and it works without problem.

My system:

- Ubintu 13.10 64 bit
- Gcc 4.8.1
- Qt 5.2.2 (git)

Comment: I really can't understand what going on with my project.

Comment: My project got crazy. Debugger shows wrong values, for example 186 for boolean value what was initialized with `true`. Some class valiables looks deleted but they was created and initialized before. So when I try to get it the program crash.

Comment: One more strange thing:
In code I have:


CoreManager * cm = CoreManager::instance();
connect(cm,SIGNAL(AddAction(QAction*)),this,SLOT(AddMenuAction(QAction*)));


I get error: No such signal Config::AddWidgetSignal
But it is not Config instance but CoreManager ... hmm

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing badly wrong with the code you show, except that you want to pass a const *reference* to the string, but that's not the cause of the problem. The `Settings` constructor should have the following signature:

```
Settings::Settings(const QString & file, QObject * parent)
```

You should re-run qmake on the project, clean and rebuild it, and try again. If it still doesn't work, then you have a memory bug and the change of the platform simply exposes a latent bug in your code.

Comment: Yes, reference works. But why passing by value works on Windows and not works on Linux?
And other problems - it looks like x86 and x64 code was mixed but I've double cheched it. Qt was compiled as x64.

Comment: @folibis Either one is supposed to work. You have other errors that merely manifest in this place in the code, but they are unrelated.